# How remove label from seaborn left axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-bar-chart

I've made a square pie chart by interposing three bar charts on top of one another.

The chart is exactly what I want, with the exception of the left axis label ("Dog").

I tried `ax.set(xlabel=None)` - this doesn't work.

I tried adding a row with no name and zero value, but this had no impact.

I tried switch the location of the x and y value, as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718136/python-seaborn-horizon-bar-plot-tick-axis-label-after-groupby?rq=2) but this had no impact.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': ['Dogs', 'Birds', 'Cats'],
    'percent': [20.444444, 53.629630, 100.000000],
})

#split dataframe into individual barplots
df_1 = df.iloc[[0]]
df_2 = df.iloc[[1]]
df_3 = df.iloc[[2]]


sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

#set size
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 10))

#make barplots

sns.barplot(x="percent", y="index", data=df_3,
            color='#d7301f',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent", y="index", data=df_2,
            color='#fc8d59',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent", y="index", data=df_1,
            color='#fdcc8a',ax=None)

#add text

ax.text(0.1, 0.5, "Dogs (20%)", ha="center", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes,color='#313639',fontsize=30)

ax.text(0.35, 0.5, "Birds (33%)", ha="center", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes,color='#313639',fontsize=30)

ax.text(0.76, 0.5, "Cats (46%)", ha="center", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes,color='#313639',fontsize=30)

#remove ticks and labels
ax.set(xticklabels=[])
ax.set(xlabel=None)
ax.set(ylabel=None)

sns.despine(bottom = True, left = True)
ax.grid(False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a tick label, so `ax.set(yticklabels=[])` will do the job!

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': ['Dogs', 'Birds', 'Cats'],
    'percent': [20.444444, 53.629630, 100.000000],
})

#split dataframe into individual barplots
df_1 = df.iloc[[0]]
df_2 = df.iloc[[1]]
df_3 = df.iloc[[2]]


sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

#set size
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 10))

#make barplots

sns.barplot(x="percent", y="index", data=df_3,
            color='#d7301f',ax=ax)

sns.barplot(x="percent", y="index", data=df_2,
            color='#fc8d59',ax=ax)

sns.barplot(x="percent", y="index", data=df_1,
            color='#fdcc8a',ax=ax)
ax.set(yticklabels=[])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have saved me hours and hours of trying to solve this.  Many thanks!